# Qt with webRTC how to implement

Tags: c++, qt, webrtc, qwebkit

I need to transfer live desktop screen data(like remote desktop) to a client application a browser, and user can view remote desktop in browser, I am thinking of implementing it with webRTC and Qt. the webRTC data channel I can use to transfer the desktop data. Only problem is how to interface it with QT. When I look in internet I have few methods.

1. Implement with native c++ webRTC  and communicate with the browser. I  searched lot to get a working c++ webRTC  application but couldn't successfully run.
2. Implement with Qt webengine and java script. I read documentation about Qt webkit bridge, I hope I can pass data between Qt C++ part and Javascript part without much delay.

And I am not sure is there any good method exist. Please suggest me the right method.